# How do I ping Binance via websocket

Tags: websocket, binance

I'm following the docs at https://docs.binance.us/#websocket-streams.

It does mention ping frames but when I try to ping, I get back the error:

```
{"error":{"code":3,"msg":"Invalid JSON: expected value at line 1 column 1"}}
```

Using the exact same code but with a client socket connected to Bitmex for example, I get back a successful pong response. Connection, subscription, etc, all work fine for me, which leads me to believe that there is some issue with ping specifically.

For reference, here is the SSCE in C#, my code boils down to:

```
byte[] buffer = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("PING");
ArraySegment<byte> byte_array = new ArraySegment<byte>(buffer);
var _socket = new System.Net.WebSockets.ClientWebSocket();
await _socket.SendAsync(byte_array, WebSocketMessageType.Text, true, CancellationToken.None);
```

As mentioned, this works as expected with other exchanges.

So how do I get ping working with Binance?

Comment: Well you seem to just be sending the wrong data. As per the documentation that you linked, the purpose of the ping is: `Ping a user data stream to keep it alive.` and it needs to be a JSON message that you may view here: https://docs.binance.us/#start-user-data-stream-websocket

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.binance.us/#ping-user-data-stream-websocket
This should help you. The recommendation is to send the ping every 30 mins.
To keep alive the data stream

Answer (score 0):

First we need to distinguish **ping frame** and **ping message**.

**ping frame**: It's from websocket protocol. Opcode is 0x9.

**ping message**: It's custom message base on websocket **text frame**. Text frame opcode is 0x1.

**From binance doc:**

> The websocket server will send a ping frame every 3 minutes. If the websocket server does not receive a pong frame back from the connection within a 10 minute period, the connection will be disconnected. Unsolicited pong frames are allowed.

So we know, we should use **ping frame** but not **ping message**. For example, huobi exchange use **ping message**.

For your question, it maybe useful:

```
ArraySegment<byte> pingBuffer = new ArraySegment<byte>(new byte[] { 0x89, 0x00 });
WebSocketMessageType messageType = WebSocketMessageType.Binary;
bool endOfMessage = true;
await webSocket.SendAsync(pingBuffer, messageType, endOfMessage, CancellationToken.None);
```